# CPU Resource Management For Bulk Attachment Insert Share Host

Tags: memory, bulk-import

I've created a page on a shared host which loops through a series of posts and then attaches images to each of the posts. The images are already on the server and are copied into the WP-Content folder. It 'works' but after about the 3rd iteration of the loop, the web page gives a timeout error and if I look at the server's CPU utilisation it is 100%.

So the question(s) are:
1) Is there some sort of generalised 'garbage collection' I should be using after each iteration of the loop to prevent the CPU/memory build-up?

2) Failing that, is there a tool I can use to profile what is going on, with a shared hosting account?

Here is the code for the main loop. The guts is in a separate function 'save_post()' which calls wp_insert_post and then wp_generate_attachment_metadata. I figured I'd start with asking about some -general- memory/resource management before going into the weeds with that. I assume this would be many times more efficient if I could use bulk SQL statements rather than individual SQL requests for each insert/attachment but it seems like there is too much complexity in what happens when WP creates thumbnails and assigns postmeta for me to want to tackle that for a one-off project.

`                       $args = array('post_type' => 'ims_gallery', 
                                      'post_status' => 'draft',
                                      'posts_per_page' => 10);
                        $pwp_query = new WP_Query($args);

```
                    while( $pwp_query->have_posts() ) : $pwp_query->the_post();

                            $post = get_post();
                                                    // var_dump($post);
                            $gallery = $post;
                            $galid = $gallery->ID;
                            $galmeta = get_post_custom( $galid );
                            $galpath = '/' . trim( $galmeta['_ims_folder_path'][0], '.,/' );

                            $titlename = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', get_the_title() );
                            $sourcefolder =  '/home/myserver2/public_html/source/CurrentImages/' . $titlename;

                            echo('Processing: ' . $sourcefolder);
                            $destfolder =  '/home/myserver2/public_html/myserver.net/wp-content/_imsgalleries/gallery-' . $galid;                               
                            $_resized_destfolder = $destfolder . '/_resized';
                            $flist = '';
                            $files1 = scandir($sourcefolder);                               
                            if($files1) {
                                    $flist = implode(',', $files1);
                                    echo($galpath);
                                    // @mkdir( $destfolder, 0751, true );
                                    @mkdir( $destfolder, 0751, true );                                                                              
                                    @mkdir( $_resized_destfolder, 0751, true );                                     

                                    @shell_exec('cp -a ' . $sourcefolder . '/* ' . $destfolder);                                    

                                    // code to generate attachments is here.
                                    save_post( $galid, $post );

                            }
                            else
                            echo('No files for: ' . $sourcefolder);

                    endwhile; ?>
```

`

Comment: You can use php `sleep()` function.

Comment: How would sleep() help?

Comment: It will put some delay on resource usage.

Comment: Interesting. Would there be a way to test the current memory usage at each iteration of the loop to see if it is about to 'overload'?

Comment: `memory_get_peak_usage()` could be helpful, not sure though.